# Почему говорят, что статические методы в JAVA переопределять нельзя, когда их переопределять МОЖНО?

Tags: java

Не ставьте мне, пожалуйста, минусики. Я только начинаю, и вопрос совершенно не глупый. Во всех статьях, что я читала, между переопределением и перегрузкой есть только одна разница (в сигнатурах). Поэтому совершенно естественно, что у меня возник этот вопрос.

Итак, как я поняла,  в Java нельзя переопределять статические методы.

Так же я узнала, что ПЕРЕОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕ - это когда и имена и сигнатуры у методов одинаковые.

Узнала, что ПЕРЕГРУЗКА - это когда имена у методов одинаковые, а сигнатуры разные.

В данном коде методы статические, но переопределение происходит без проблем - компилятор ошибки не выдает.

ВОПРОС: почему говорят что статические методы переопределять нельзя, когда их переопределять МОЖНО?

[image: код с результатом]

```
public class Devocka {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.myMessage();
    }
}

class A {
    public static void myMessage() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static void myMessage() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Этим примером вы ничего не доказали. Вы видите `В` в консоли, потому что написали так:

```
B b = new B();
```

Это выражение не может показать работу переопределённых методов даже там, где оно действительно есть. Для того, чтобы продемонстрировать работу переопределённых методов, вам нужно записать так:

```
А а = new B();
```

Т.е. вы создаете экземпляр класса и приводите его к переменной суперкласса. Если вы сейчас выведете переменную `а` в консоль, то увидите `А`, а не `В`. Потому что ваш метод статический, и он принадлежит классу. Вы создали экземпляр класса (объект) `В` и записали его в переменную типа класса `А`. В том случае, если ваш метод будет нестатический, то вы увидите `В`, потому что этот метод переопределён, а в переменной типа `А` записан объект типа `В`. Но в вашем случае метод статический, посему никакого отношения к объекту он не имеет, он принадлежит классу, а переменная у нас типа `А`, значит и статический метод отработает для класса `А`.